# Is this a thread safe way to initialize a [ThreadStatic]?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, thread-static

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static Foo _foo;

public static Foo CurrentFoo {
   get {
     if (_foo == null) {
         _foo = new Foo();
     }
     return _foo;
   }
}
```

Is the previous code thread safe?  Or do we need to lock the method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If its ThreadStatic there's one copy per thread.  So, by definition, its thread safe.

[This blog has some good info on ThreadStatic.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jfoscoding/are-you-familiar-with-threadstatic)

Comment: That's where my example comes from.  I'm just trying to figure out if it's possible for one thread to get _foo == null but then a thread switch occurs and another threads _foo gets new'ed up even though it isn't null?

Comment: Nope.  One _foo per thread, so context switches have no impact.

Answer (score 2):

A `[ThreadStatic]` is compiler/language magic for thread local storage. In other words, it is bound to the thread, so even if there is a context switch it doesn't matter because no other thread can access it directly.